# Discord.py Rewrite <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x108778288>

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm revisiting discord.py after a year and found that async wasn't obviously available so apparently, now I'm using rewrite and have no idea what I'm doing. I'm trying to send a simple embed but instead the bot says this:

```
'<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x108778288>'
```

Here's my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    aiuto = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="being helpful")
    await ctx.send(aiuto)
```

Comment: that went wrong. The bot says <discord.embeds.Embed...  ...288>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `embed` kwarg to message now,

```
await ctx.send(embed = aiuto)
```

Additionally, in discord.py rewrite you dont need to pass `pass_context` to `bot.command`,
`@bot.command`
also works

Answer (score 0):

The answer it:
await ctx.send(embed=aiuto)